# how to add shipping city attribute to the cart rules

Tags: cart-rule

Promotions -> shopping cart price rules -> conditions tab, there are cart attribute option like the shipping country,shipping state/province. I also want the shipping city. How to get that shipping city in the dropdown.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite /app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Rule/Condition/Address.php file with some local module and change these lines

```
public function loadAttributeOptions()
    {
        $attributes = array(
            'base_subtotal' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Subtotal'),
            'total_qty' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Total Items Quantity'),
            'weight' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Total Weight'),
            'payment_method' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Payment Method'),
            'shipping_method' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Shipping Method'),
            'postcode' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Shipping Postcode'),
            'region' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Shipping Region'),
            'region_id' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Shipping State/Province'),
            'country_id' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Shipping Country'),
        );
        $this->setAttributeOption($attributes);
        return $this;
    }
```

to

```
public function loadAttributeOptions()
    {
        $attributes = array(
            'base_subtotal' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Subtotal'),
            'total_qty' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Total Items Quantity'),
            'weight' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Total Weight'),
            'payment_method' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Payment Method'),
            'shipping_method' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Shipping Method'),
            'postcode' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Shipping Postcode'),
            'region' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Shipping Region'),
            'region_id' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Shipping State/Province'),
            'country_id' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Shipping Country'),
            'city' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Shipping City'),
        );
        $this->setAttributeOption($attributes);
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, a better way is to use salesrule_rule_condition_combine event to add additional address attributes

Answer (score 0):

For magento2 users you can modify following file

> vendor\magento\module-sales-rule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address.php

but make sure you create file in app folder for modification

> app/code/Companyname/Module/Model/Rule/Condition/Address.php

search same function name

```
public function loadAttributeOptions()
```